# Prove $[(P \lor Q \lor R) \land (P \implies S) \land (Q \implies S) \land (R \implies S)] \implies S $ is a tautology.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm currently having a difficult time proving this tautology and I only made a small progress by trying to prove it. I'm trying to use a proof by contradiction and this is what I have achieved so far...

1. By negating the statement:
   $\neg\left(\left[\left(P \lor Q \lor R \right) \land  \left(P \implies S \right) \land \left(Q \implies S \right) \land \left(R \implies S \right) \right] \implies S \right) $
2. By the implication, $\left(P \implies Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q\right)$:
   $\neg \left( \neg \left[ \left(P \lor Q \lor R \right)\land \left(P \implies S \right) \land \left(Q \implies S \right) \land \left(R \implies S \right) \right] \lor S \right)$
3. By elimination:
   $\left[\left(P \lor Q \lor R \right) \land \left(P\implies Q\right) \land \left(Q   \implies S\right) \land \left(R \implies S \right)\right] \land \neg S $
4. By using the implication rule again:
   $\left[\left(P\lor Q \lor R \right) \land \left(\neg P \lor S\right) \land \left(\neg Q \lor S \right) \land \left(\neg R \lor S \right)\right] \land \neg S $

and thus, I am now lost. I don't know how to further go from #4 onwards, or if my approach to the problem was correct. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you already done the simpler one $$[(P \lor Q) \land (P \implies S) \land (Q \implies S)] \implies S\;?$$  I so, can we apply that one to deduce the new one?

Comment: oh, I actually haven't tried this one yet.

Comment: A proof ny contradiction works nicely here. Namely, if you assume that the hypothesis is true and the conclusion is false for some assignment of truth values of $P,Q,R,S$ you will quickly reach absurdity

Comment: I love the community here. It was my first time making an account and I'm loving it here! I did a proof by contradiction, and I finally arrived at the contradiction i wanted to show. But my solution is a bit long but nonetheless i finally solved the problem because of everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

$$[(P \lor Q \lor R) \land (P \implies S) \land (Q \implies S) \land (R \implies S)] \implies S =$$
$$= [(P \lor Q \lor R) \land (\neg P \lor S) \land (\neg Q \lor S) \land (\neg R \lor S)] \implies S =$$
$$= [(P \lor Q \lor R) \land ((\neg P \land \neg Q \land \neg R) \lor S)]  \implies S = $$
$$=[((P \lor Q \lor R) \land \neg (P \lor  Q \lor R)) \lor ((P \lor Q \lor R)\land S]  \implies S =$$
$$= (0 \lor ((P \lor Q \lor R)\land S)  \implies S=$$
$$=(P \lor Q \lor R)\land S \implies S =$$
$$=\neg((P \lor Q \lor R)\land S) \lor S=$$
$$=\neg(P \lor Q \lor R)\lor \neg S) \lor S=$$
$$=\neg(P \lor Q \lor R)\lor (\neg S \lor S)=$$
$$=\neg(P \lor Q \lor R)\lor 1=$$
$$=1 $$

Comment: Maybe say something about your use of  the "modular law": $$(A \wedge B) \vee  C = A \wedge (B \vee C)$$  Note: it is valid **provided** $C{ \implies} A$ is true.

Comment: what logical equivalence is used in $\neg\left(\left(P \lor Q \lor R \right) \land \neg S \right) \lor S$ to obtain  $$\neg \left(P \lor Q \lor R \right) \lor \neg S \right) \lor S $$ ?

Comment: @Mathsochist_777 : $\neg(p \land q)=\neg p \lor \neg q$

Comment: @GEdgar : I updated my soution.

Comment: @LionHeart: Thank you! your solution helped me to finally answer my problem. Unfortunately I couldn't vote up since I am newbie and I need at least 15 reputation to cast my vote.

Comment: However, you can "accept" the answer to your question.